# Test an entire PHP website

Tags: php, testing

I have inherited an big existing PHP application (website actually) that runs on Apache.

My problem is that there is only the code which is a bit ... tangled and I know there is a lot of errors code.

I would like to have/build a tool that can call all URLs (or scripts) of my web site and detect if there is exception or errors?

Do you know some kind of lead to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. turn on error_reporting in php.ini
2. point wget to the website and ask to recursively download everything:

   wget -r http://your-url
3. grep PHP Warnings, Notices and Errors in the output.

Comment: @Lohoris - true, but I'm guessing you'd get a great deal of coverage, which, given what the OP has to work with, seems like a lot better than nothing.

Comment: I really like this :)  
Simple and will cover most of my site  
  
@Lohoris - you're wight and I may combine this with your answer to have a complete coverage of the php pages  
  
Thanks a lot guys!!!

Comment: how can we do this under windows ?

Answer (score 0):

for the syntax only, you can use the following:

```
looris@Lohoris-WhiteBook:~ $ cat bin/syntax-check 
#!/bin/bash
find $@ -name '*.php' -exec php -l {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the pages in the website have some internal link pointing to it, you can write a crawler that browses the whole site, that's basically a matter of having a starting point (index.php), extracting all the links on it with a regex or something and go hitting each of the links and doing the same procedure recursively (like traversing a tree :). There are some scripts to generate sitemaps that already do that.

This would be the solution if all the pages can be reached from internal links and no matter how your application is designed.

Other possible solutions are:

1. List all .php files that are accessible in your "public_html" dir and hit them with curl or wget
2. If it's an MVC architecture, try to list all the actions in all controllers and also hit them with curl or wget