# test entire php website with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, testing, web-crawler

I am looking forward to test my php wesbite made with the help of symfony2 under windows.

I am aware you can write unit and functional tests, but given a lack of time, I'm looking for a more automatic solution.

EDIT:
There are some example as to how build php unit test in symfony doc, but it seems you have to hardcode the urls. And the forms have to be tested with data you put in it yourself.

Would that not be possible to write something generic ? (Loop through routes, find every form and populate with data passing html5 validation) ? Did someone already do that ? How would you approach the solution ?

Also, I have seen this post [Test an entire PHP website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871789/test-an-entire-php-website) but this does not work under windows and forms are not tested.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."  @mkemp6 - you might want to note this when reviewing items.

Comment: I edited to make it compliant

Comment: I do not think testing should be "generic" or however you want to automate it. Looks like you only want to do functional tests? Then I suggest behat. If you want to do more detailed testing, use also phpunit, prophecy, phpspec, but test should be written in advance anyway. If your code is how it should be, testing is really easy and doesnt take much time.

Comment: well, I am under the impression I need to write custom tests for every function or at least controller action of my application. then do I need to write tests for my tests ? ^^ I'm joking, I know it's important but I don't see how I can make it quick if it's not generic. I know it won't be perfect if generic but I could accomodate for something in between.